# Change ul style on scroll to div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have menu with four `<ul>`s and in the container of the page I have four boxes.
The first `ul` for the first box, second `ul` for the second box, third `ul`.... and it goes on

When I scroll to the first box first `ul`'s style change to different style, then when I scroll to the second box second `ul`'s style change to same different style AND the first `ul`'s style return to its original style.. and like that.

The problem is when I scroll to the last box, the fourth `ul` style change to different style, BUT when I pause the box and goes to a space without boxes the fourth `ul`'s style STILL the same style and does NOT return to it's original style as you can see here:

http://ge.tt/6YcYZ1h/v/0

I tried something like this (http://ge.tt/6PeKY1h/v/0) but it didn't work 100% as you can see.  Also I explained some things and where's my problem exactly in the codes.
CODES HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/YZvKX/

Comment: Could you add the code you used?

Comment: You can download the code, just press download in the page I posted(here first http://ge.tt/6YcYZ1h/v/0, then I tried this http://ge.tt/6PeKY1h/v/0)

Comment: Sorry to be so frank but what makes you think I want your code on my hard drive, if you want answers from people don't make them do things! Make sure they have the information they need without setting up their whole development environment  first!

So make sure:
**1.** Add your code in the post
**2.** Create a JSFiddle with your code (http://jsfiddle.net)
**3.** Let's get some answers! :D

Comment: I can't post that on jsfiddle, its window is VERY small to get the page

Comment: Use http://jsbin.com/ then

Comment: Here's my webpage: http://ge.tt/9jACz1h/v/0
Press on "download" and enter the page, ZOOM IN on the menu that placed in the beginning of the page, a scrollbar will appear just go left and right with the scrollbar and you can see it's NOT for the menu it's for the content, and you can see some of the ULs disappear and you can't see it because no scrollbar for the menu.
JUST try to edit the codes for the webpage and change the position to absolute and do the same steps, you can see it works with absolute position but doesn't work with fixed, and I need it with fixed position, that;s my problem

Comment: Isn't this question largely the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599224/menu-ul-style-change-on-scroll-to-div)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer for this problem but here is a fiddle.

You can simply use jquery to add and remove classes to change the style of your button.

```
$(".scroll").click(function (event) {
    $('#menu li').addClass('menutext');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 59
    }, 800);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('menutext');
    $(this).parent().addClass('menutext2');
});
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YZvKX/1/